# Correctly querying a raster mask only

Tags: postgis, raster, st-intersects

I have a `rasterA` (whole Scandinavia, with values from 0-255) and a `rasterB` (in blue, a small part of south of Norway, entirely inside `rasterA`). I want to query the pixels of `rasterA` which are inside `rasterB`.

Will this query return only those pixels which overlap, or will it return values for the whole of `rasterA`, since `rasterA` and `rasterB` overlap?

Query:
`SELECT A.rid, pvc FROM rasterA AS A, rasterB AS B, ST_ValueCount(A.rast,1) AS pvc WHERE st_intersects(A.rast, B.rast);`

`rasterA`(white) and `raster B` (blue): 
[image]

Also, I'm importing the raster into PostGIS like so:

`raster2pgsql \
    -s 3857 -I -C -Y \
    -t ${TILESIZE} \
    -l 4,32,128 \
    ${RASTERFILE} $TABLENAME |
    psql -q --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1`

Can this have anything do to with the faulty results I'm getting?

Comment: Thanks @JohnBarça, you're a real hero for answering all my PG questions! :) I'm getting unexpected results of values, they are somewhat off (0-10%) from expectations. More details here if you're interested, https://github.com/systemapic/systemapic.js/issues/216, if you have any clue as to why, please don't hesitate to tip me!

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely misread the above. Yes, ST_Intersection is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return for  the  whole  raster.   You need to use something like ST_Intersection to just get the portion that overlaps. http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_ST_Intersection.html

So something like:

```
SELECT A.rid, pvc 
  FROM rasterA AS A INNER JOIN rasterB AS B ON 
      ST_Intersects(A.rast, B.rast)   
       , LATERAL 
         ST_ValueCount(ST_Intersection(A.rast,B.rast, 'BAND1') ,1) AS pvc;
```

Since you only care about band1 values the other approach to do this if you don't have the same alignment is to use ST_Clip with ST_polygon.  So would look like

```
SELECT A.rid, pvc 
  FROM rasterA AS A INNER JOIN rasterB AS B ON 
      ST_Intersects(A.rast, B.rast)   
       , LATERAL 
         ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(A.rast,ST_Polygon(B.rast) ) ,1) AS pvc;
```

Comment: Thanks @LR1234567! Looks good. However, I'm getting `The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment` on this query now... Any idea why?

Comment: `The rasters have different scales on the X axis` is the reason. Can I incorporate an auto-alignment in the query directly?

Comment: Hmm might be easier to do with ST_Clip then.  I'll add an alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @LR1234567! Spot on! :) Learned a lot from this, thanks a lot!